# set hook with variable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i have in app component array hook that i need to update, but i have one variable that i cannot update , dont understand why

***app component code***

```
function App() {
  const [coins, setCoins] = useState([{name:'Shekel',price:2}, {name:'Dollar',price:3}, {name:'Rubal',price:20}])
  const [changeHistory, setChangeHistory] = useState([])

  const updateHistoryChange=(from,to,changeRate,amount)=>{
    setChangeHistory([...changeHistory,{from:from,to:to,changeRate:changeRate,amout:amount,index:changeHistory.length}])
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={() => { return <HomePage coins={coins} updateHistoryChange={updateHistoryChange} />}}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

***Home Page component***

```
export default function HomePage(props) {
    const [inputMoney, setInputMoney] = useState()
    const [from, setFrom] = useState()
    const [to, setTo] = useState()
    const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false)
    const [rateChange,setRateChange]=useState()

    const calculate = () => {
        debugger
        let sum = 0;
        let fromChange;
        let toChange;
        for (let i = 0; i < props.coins.length; i++) {
            if (props.coins[i].name == from) {
                fromChange = props.coins[i].price;
                break;
            }
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < props.coins.length; i++) {
            if (props.coins[i].name == to) {
                toChange = props.coins[i].price;
                setRateChange(toChange)//not updating it is always undifined
                break;
            }
        }
        sum = toChange * inputMoney;
        console.log(`${rateChange}`);
        props.updateHistoryChange(from,to,rateChange,inputMoney)
        window.alert(`${sum}`);

    }
    const redirect = () => {
        window.location.href = 'https://www.facebook.com/';
    }

    const isHid = () => {
        if (flag) {

        }
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Exchange</h1>
            <p>From:<select id='from' onChange={(element) =>{setFrom(element.target.value)}}>
                {props.coins.map((element) => {
                    return (
                        <option value={`${element.name}`} >
                            {element.name}
                        </option>
                    )
                })}
            </select>
                <input type='number' placeholder='type your money amount' onChange={(element) => { setInputMoney(Number(element.target.value)) }}></input>
            </p>

            <p>
                To:<select id='to' onChange={(element) => { setTo(element.target.value) }}>
                    {props.coins.map((element) => {
                        return (
                            <option value={`${element.name}`}>
                                {element.name}
                            </option>
                        )
                    })}
                </select>
            </p>
            <button onClick={calculate} disabled={!inputMoney}>Start</button>
            <button>Update</button>
            <button onClick={redirect}>Share on facebook</button>
            <button>View your exchange list</button>
            {isHid()}
        </div>
    )
}
```

in function calculate when i am setting rateChange like so:

```
setRateChange(toChange)
```

it is not updating my hook
also tried this not working as well:

setRateChange(props.coins[i].price)

Comment: make  a stackbitz http://www.stackblitz.com

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue and provided the explanation below. Please find the working link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-szjqbu?file=src/App.js

There are two things that I would like to explain you here:-

1. React batches the updates to the component state therefore if you try to access the updated state immediately after updating the state you will not get the updated state.
   As you are trying to access the state variable `rateChange` in the log immediatly after calling `setRateChange` therefore you are not getting the updated value.
2. In `App.js` where you are defining the `Route`; `component` prop of `HomePage` is an inline method which is always returning the new `HomePage` instance which is resulting into state reset as it is new component previous component got unmounted.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't update the `rateChange` variable is because when you call `calculate` you trigger a re-render on the parent component which causes the `HomePage` component to unmount and then re-mount, this will reset the state of `rateChange` to its initial or default value `undefined`.

To fix this you need to ensure that the `HomePage` isn't unmounted. To do that you need to fix what causes that to occur. Here's whats happening:

- When you call `props.updateHistoryChange` a set state is called on the parent component in `App` which triggers a re-render
- a re-render on `App` begins this causes its children to be checked for updates
- the Route for `HomePage` is checked to see if it needs to
  re-rendered, because the `HomePage` component is passed as a
  function (without memoization) the `react-router-dom` (I'm assuming
  this is what you are using) sees a new `HomePage` component and
  re-renders a fresh component unmounting the previous one because the `component` prop has changed

By memoizing the component using `useCallback`

```
  const updateHistoryChange = useCallback(
    (from, to, changeRate, amount) => {
      setChangeHistory((changeHistory) => [
        ...changeHistory,
        {
          from: from,
          to: to,
          changeRate: changeRate,
          amout: amount,
          index: changeHistory.length
        }
      ]);
    },
    [setChangeHistory]
  );

  const HomePageRoute = useCallback(
    () => <HomePage coins={coins} updateHistoryChange={updateHistoryChange} />,
    [coins, updateHistoryChange]
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePageRoute} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
```

or using jsx

```
  <Route exact path="/">
     <HomePage coins={coins} updateHistoryChange={updateHistoryChange} />
  </Route>
```

The state change on the variable will persist, heres a [codesandebox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-gates-o0180?file=/src/App.js) of the latter in practice